# problems with cordova.file.externalRootDirectory

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-file

i want to read files from external directory, but  cordova.file.externalRootDirectory always returns the internal device memory "file:///storage/emulated/0/"  ???

Answer (score 0):

plese follow the link I hope you will find solution in this link https://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/07/15/Cordova-Sample-Reading-a-text-file

Comment: thanks, but mu problem was to read file from external SD card(I inserted micro card), i only got android's internal memory even when i use cordova.file.externalRootDirectory.

Answer (score 0):

The [getExternalSdCardDetails()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#getexternalsdcarddetails) method of [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) can be used to get a reference to removable micro SD card locations:

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getExternalSdCardDetails(function(details){
    details.forEach(function(detail){
        if(type === "application"){
            console.log("Writable?" + detail.canWrite); //TRUE
            cordova.file.externalSdCardApplicationStorageDirectory = detail.filePath; 
            // Write files to external SD card using this
        }else{ // type === "root"
            console.log("Writable?" + detail.canWrite); //FALSE
            cordova.file.externalSdCardRootDirectory = detail.filePath;
            // Read files from external SD card root using this
        }
    });
}, function(error){
    console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Try the [example project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin-example) which illustrates use of `getExternalSdCardDetails()`. I'm the author of cordova-diagnostic-plugin so if the example doesn't work I'd appreciate if you could open an issue with details of your test device(s).

Answer (score 0):

Insert legacy application external storge on file config.xml

```
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" />
```